# Really basic python3 user input type

Tags: python-3.x

I want to ask a user for a number(among other things) and if they input anything other than an int, it should tell them to try again.

I'm still getting use to python syntax, what's the best way to do this?

excerpt below of what I tried:

```
try:
    num = int(i)
except ValueError:
    while type(num) != int:
        num = input("Please input an actual number or q to quit: ")
```

Comment: what is the purpose of the try-except?

Comment: Have you read through the python documentation? There are no doubt gazillions of examples there and on the internet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while True:
    num = input("Input a number. ")
    if num.isdigit()==False:
        print("Try again.")
    else:
        break
```

This should work unless if there's a negative value entered in which case you need to make a check if the first character is a - sign.

Comment: read [asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response) - there are several better options in it. - yours f.e. does not lead to having a number at the end, negatives have to be handled seperately as you mentioned and whitespace might throw yours off as well - also read [isdigit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) - it represents digits that are not ok when you need an integer from it  (edge cases)

Comment: Ah ok. This was just a solution that I used off the top of my head but I'll check that out. Thanks